# How do I fix pixelated/jagged shadows on Cycles bake?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to bake my floor mesh which has a bunch of object's shadows on it. The problem is my baked texture's shadow is really jagged/pixelated even from a far distance it is noticeable.
[image]

Any thing I should look in to help to fix this issue? I've tried changing up my UV unwrapping but it doesn't seem to help. I tried jpg, hdr, and png image texture formats, and increasing the texture to 4K and sampled more. I also added denoising node and anti-aliasing node in the compositor.
[image]

Here's what I want it to look like and it looks like this in the viewport in render mode, it's super smooth:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here really seem to just be texel density.

Think of your texture resolution as your pixel budget, and your UVs as how you allocate pixels around your model.
If you don't have enough pixels at some place, you either change the UV size on that area, at the expanse of other areas, or you make the resolution bigger. Or both.